# Podio API - Groupings are missing from Views in C#

Tags: podio

I am working with the Podio api in C# and "Groupings" is missing from the View and ViewCreateUpdateRequest model.

When I use the [sandbox call](https://developers.podio.com/doc/views/get-view-27450) the result includes the groupings. So I'm thinking it is missing in the C# nuget package. Is there another way to access groupings for both Get View and Update View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly they are not maintaining the SDK for C#, but you can download their code from https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet and update the code yourself.

That's what I did, I change the following

1. ItemId data type from Integer to Long
2. Added Groupings in View (Below is my View looks like)

   ```cs
   public class View
   {
       [JsonProperty("view_id")]
       public string ViewId { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("created_on")]
       public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("sort_by")]
       public string SortBy { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("sort_desc")]
       public string SortDesc { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("filters")]
       public JArray Filters { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("fields")]
       public JObject Fields { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("groupings")]
       public JObject Groupings { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("created_by")]
       public ByLine CreatedBy { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("layout")]
       public string Layout { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("type")]
       public string Type { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("rights")]
       public string[] Rights { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("filter_id")]
       public string FilterId { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty("items")]
       public int Items { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Search for NuGet Package: Podio.Async by acl2